# How can I rotate (in game,) with click-drag rather than keyboard keys?

Tags: game-engine

I've made a game where I rotate an object, (the entire scene actually, as everything is parented to one central empty,) using the arrow keys, but I'd rather like it to rotate with click-drag. At the same time, I'm using the left mouse button to select objects and move them around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it's nicer to rotate the camera around the object, but the logic brick setup is the same:

[image]

If you want to rotate the camera, put an empty at the rotation center, apply the logic to the empty, and parent the camera to the empty.

Comment: Outstanding. I almost got there on my own. I did the two mouse sensors, but on actuator I did simple movement. - Why is it nicer to move the camera? Fewer things moving more efficient?

Comment: I just think it's more intuitive for the user. No technical reason.